# SegWit Tx taking way too long

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness

Wondering what can be causing a Tx to take from from 19:48 (sent) to 22:44 (finally arrive to destination address). With Segwit implemented in both sides. 
The mempool looks way lower than past days. Any ideas? 
This was way scary. I used the Tx ID to check the Tx and all it came up with was a Not Found error in every block explorer. 
At around 22h. the Tx suddenly appeared. In general, the mempool is way lower than previous days, but it has been a huge spike if looking at the 24 hours chart. Would this be the reason of the delay? Thanks.

Comment: In general, there is no reason to be 'scared' if a transaction does not show up in a block explorer's mempool, or does not confirm immediately. Pending txs cannot be 'lost', your bitcoins were perfectly safe. If it took that long to show up in the mempool of various block explorers, then I would guess that your wallet was not properly connected to network, and thus not able to relay your txs to other nodes.

Comment: Interesting. I could see at the end of the receiver that the Tx was detected as "incoming Tx", however, the Tx did not show up on any explorer. This is the first time something like this happens. I find it really, really weird.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention is CET time, just for reference. Looking at the 24 h charts of the mempool you can get an idea of the time frame I refer too - there is a spike.

Comment: So the problem here seems like the fees were too low. Not that I could manually adjust them though. If the core issue for a segwit delayed Tx is the same as for pre-segwit Tx, then this question is duplicate. I wasn't sure the root cause was the same. Thanks.